# How to implement private chat in ios using firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, segue, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have implemented private chat in my ios app. However, it is not so private. When I send a message that I intend to send to one person, everyone in the app can see it. I have three view controllers in play here. [image]

The FirstViewController has a list of users, and when the cell is clicked it is segued to the DetailedViewController. In this viewController, it only lists the details of the user clicked on. Next, when I press the compose button in the DetailedViewController, the goal is to segue to MessageUserController. This is where I am stuck. This is the code to segue to the MessageUserController:

```
var username: String?

@IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "sendMessageToUser", sender: self.username)
}

override public func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "sendMessageToUser", let chatVc = segue.destination as? MessageViewController else {
        return
    } 
    chatVc.senderId = self.loggedInUser?.uid
    chatVc.senderDisplayName = self.username
}
```

I assume the sender could be the username because it is unique to the user. When I click on a user to chat with, it works fine but when I click on another user, the chat between the first users are already displayed in the new user's chatController

In the firstViewController, username is passed like this:

```
if segue.identifier == "UsersProfile" {
    if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath{
        let vc = segue.destination as! UsersProfileViewController
        let post = self.posts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
        let username = post["username"] as? String
        vc.username = username 
    }
}
```

entire view controller:

```
import UIKit
import Photos
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import JSQMessagesViewController

class SendMessageViewController: JSQMessagesViewController {
    var username: String?
    //var receiverData = AnyObject?()

    var messages = [JSQMessage]()
    private var photoMessageMap = [String: JSQPhotoMediaItem]()
    private let imageURLNotSetKey = "NOTSET"
    lazy var outgoingBubbleImageView: JSQMessagesBubbleImage = self.setupOutgoingBubble()
    lazy var incomingBubbleImageView: JSQMessagesBubbleImage = self.setupIncomingBubble()
    var rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    var messageRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages")
    private var newMessageRefHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle?
    private lazy var usersTypingQuery: FIRDatabaseQuery =
        self.rootRef.child("typingIndicator").queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: true)
    lazy var storageRef: FIRStorageReference = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com")
    private var updatedMessageRefHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle?
    private lazy var userIsTypingRef: FIRDatabaseReference =
        self.rootRef.child("typingIndicator").child(self.senderId) // 1
    private var localTyping = false // 2
    var isTyping: Bool {
        get {
            return localTyping
        }
        set {
            // 3
            localTyping = newValue
            userIsTypingRef.setValue(newValue)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.senderId = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.23, green:0.73, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]

        self.navigationItem.title = senderDisplayName
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.white

        // No avatars
        collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = CGSize.zero
        collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = CGSize.zero

         observeMessages()


    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        observeTyping()

    }

    deinit {
        if let refHandle = newMessageRefHandle {
            messageRef.removeObserver(withHandle: refHandle)

        }

        if let refHandle = updatedMessageRefHandle {
            messageRef.removeObserver(withHandle: refHandle)
        }

    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
        return messages[indexPath.item]
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messages.count
    }

    private func setupOutgoingBubble() -> JSQMessagesBubbleImage {
        let bubbleImageFactory = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory()
        return bubbleImageFactory!.outgoingMessagesBubbleImage(with: UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleBlue())
    }

    private func setupIncomingBubble() -> JSQMessagesBubbleImage {
        let bubbleImageFactory = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory()
        return bubbleImageFactory!.incomingMessagesBubbleImage(with: UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleLightGray())
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageBubbleImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource! {
        let message = messages[indexPath.item] // 1
        if message.senderId == senderId { // 2
            return outgoingBubbleImageView
        } else { // 3
            return incomingBubbleImageView
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {
        return nil
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout!, heightForMessageBubbleTopLabelAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
        return 15
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell
        let message = messages[indexPath.item]

        if message.senderId == senderId {
            cell.textView?.textColor = UIColor.white
        } else {
            cell.textView?.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
        return cell
    }

    //ADD A NEW MESSAGE
    private func addMessage(withId id: String, name: String, text: String) {
        if let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, displayName: name, text: text) {
            messages.append(message)
        }
    }

    override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!) {

        let itemRef = rootRef.child("messages").childByAutoId() // 1
        let messageItem = [ // 2
            "senderId": senderId!,
            "ReceiverName": senderDisplayName!,
            "text": text!,

            ]

        itemRef.setValue(messageItem) // 3

        JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageSentSound() // 4

        finishSendingMessage() // 5
        isTyping = false
    }

    private func observeMessages() {
               // 1.
        let messageQuery = rootRef.child("messages").queryLimited(toLast: 25)


        // 2. We can use the observe method to listen for new
        // messages being written to the Firebase DB
        newMessageRefHandle = messageQuery.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            // 3
            let messageData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

            if let id = messageData["senderId"] as String!, let name = messageData["ReceiverName"] as String!, let text = messageData["text"] as String!, text.characters.count > 0 {
                // 4
                self.addMessage(withId: id, name: name, text: text)

                // 5
                self.finishReceivingMessage()
            } else if let id = messageData["senderId"] as String!,
                let photoURL = messageData["photoURL"] as String! { // 1
                // 2
                if let mediaItem = JSQPhotoMediaItem(maskAsOutgoing: id == self.senderId) {
                    // 3
                    self.addPhotoMessage(withId: id, key: snapshot.key, mediaItem: mediaItem)
                    // 4
                    if photoURL.hasPrefix("gs://") {
                        self.fetchImageDataAtURL(photoURL, forMediaItem: mediaItem, clearsPhotoMessageMapOnSuccessForKey: nil)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("Error! Could not decode message data")
            }
        })
        // We can also use the observer method to listen for
        // changes to existing messages.
        // We use this to be notified when a photo has been stored
        // to the Firebase Storage, so we can update the message data
        updatedMessageRefHandle = messageRef.observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in
            let key = snapshot.key
            let messageData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String> // 1

            if let photoURL = messageData["photoURL"] as String! { // 2
                // The photo has been updated.
                if let mediaItem = self.photoMessageMap[key] { // 3
                    self.fetchImageDataAtURL(photoURL, forMediaItem: mediaItem, clearsPhotoMessageMapOnSuccessForKey: key) // 4
                }
            }
        })
    }

    override func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        super.textViewDidChange(textView)
        // If the text is not empty, the user is typing
        isTyping = textView.text != ""
    }
    private func observeTyping() {
        let typingIndicatorRef = rootRef.child("typingIndicator")
        userIsTypingRef = typingIndicatorRef.child(senderId)
        userIsTypingRef.onDisconnectRemoveValue()
        usersTypingQuery = typingIndicatorRef.queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: true)

        // 1
        usersTypingQuery.observe(.value) { (data: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            // 2 You're the only one typing, don't show the indicator
            if data.childrenCount == 1 && self.isTyping {
                return
            }

            // 3 Are there others typing?
            self.showTypingIndicator = data.childrenCount > 0
            self.scrollToBottom(animated: true)
        }
    }

    func sendPhotoMessage() -> String? {
        let itemRef = messageRef.childByAutoId()

        let messageItem = [
            "photoURL": imageURLNotSetKey,
            "senderId": senderId!,
            ]

        itemRef.setValue(messageItem)

        JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageSentSound()

        finishSendingMessage()
        return itemRef.key
    }
    func setImageURL(_ url: String, forPhotoMessageWithKey key: String) {
        let itemRef = messageRef.child(key)
        itemRef.updateChildValues(["photoURL": url])
    }
    override func didPressAccessoryButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self as! UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate
        if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera)) {
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        } else {
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        }

        present(picker, animated: true, completion:nil)
    }

    private func addPhotoMessage(withId id: String, key: String, mediaItem: JSQPhotoMediaItem) {
        if let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, displayName: "", media: mediaItem) {
            messages.append(message)

            if (mediaItem.image == nil) {
                photoMessageMap[key] = mediaItem
            }

            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    private func fetchImageDataAtURL(_ photoURL: String, forMediaItem mediaItem: JSQPhotoMediaItem, clearsPhotoMessageMapOnSuccessForKey key: String?) {
        // 1
        let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: photoURL)

        // 2
        storageRef.data(withMaxSize: INT64_MAX){ (data, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error downloading image data: \(error)")
                return
            }

            // 3
            storageRef.metadata(completion: { (metadata, metadataErr) in
                if let error = metadataErr {
                    print("Error downloading metadata: \(error)")
                    return
                }

                // 4
                if (metadata?.contentType == "image") {
                    mediaItem.image = UIImage.init(data: data!)
                } else {
                    mediaItem.image = UIImage.init(data: data!)
                }
                self.collectionView.reloadData()

                // 5
                guard key != nil else {
                    return
                }
                self.photoMessageMap.removeValue(forKey: key!)
            })
        }
    }


}

extension SendMessageViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                               didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)

        // 1
        if let photoReferenceUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {
            // Handle picking a Photo from the Photo Library
            // 2
            let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [photoReferenceUrl], options: nil)
            let asset = assets.firstObject

            // 3
            if let key = sendPhotoMessage() {
                // 4
                asset?.requestContentEditingInput(with: nil, completionHandler: { (contentEditingInput, info) in
                    let imageFileURL = contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL

                    // 5
                    let path = "\(FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)/\(Int(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate * 1000))/\(photoReferenceUrl.lastPathComponent)"

                    // 6
                    self.storageRef.child(path).putFile(imageFileURL!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Error uploading photo: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            return
                        }
                        // 7
                        self.setImageURL(self.storageRef.child((metadata?.path)!).description, forPhotoMessageWithKey: key)
                    }
                })
            }
        } else {
            // Handle picking a Photo from the Camera - TODO
            // 1
            let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
            // 2
            if let key = sendPhotoMessage() {
                // 3
                let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
                // 4
                let imagePath = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid + "/\(Int(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate * 1000)).jpg"
                // 5
                let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
                metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
                // 6
                storageRef.child(imagePath).put(imageData!, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error uploading photo: \(error)")
                        return
                    }
                    // 7
                    self.setImageURL(self.storageRef.child((metadata?.path)!).description, forPhotoMessageWithKey: key)
                }
            }

        }
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding correctly, but it looks more like you're having trouble clearing the data presented in your message view controller, not necessarily keeping your chat data private?

Comment: @brandonscript if that is the case, how will i go about clearing the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like this isn't a privacy issue as you state, it's simply that you're not clearing the data on your messages view controller when you load the new conversation.

Ultimately it really depends on how secure you want this to be; if you're happy having the private messages saved in memory, then don't destroy them until the user logs out — you can even keep multiple private conversations saved in a CoreData database. It's still relatively secure this way, and it's convenient for users and performant. If you prefer to destroy messages sooner, clear the data on [`viewDidDisappear`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621477-viewdiddisappear), then checking in your `prepareForSegue` method that the data is again cleared. You could also destroy the entire messages controller each time you dismiss it, if storing a strong reference isn't what you want to do.

An example of this, as a storyboard:

1. App loads
2. **User1** is logged in
3. **User1** selects private messages
4. **User1** has conversation with **User2**

---

1. **User1** switches to a conversation with **User3**
2. [pseudo-code]

   ```
   userDidChangeRecipient {
       // destroy messages view controller
       // or destroy Firebase array data and destroy the reference to the message/conversation ID
   }
   ```

---

And each time you load the view controller:

```
prepareForSegue {
    if strongRefToMessagesVC == nil {
        // instantiate a new instance of vc from nib or scratch
        // load the appropriate message/conversation ID
        // load messages
    }
}
```

---

More digging:

There's two possibilities here:

1. You're not destroying the view controller when you switch messages, and this tutorial expects you to. In that case, you need to look at when the segue ends or the user closes the messages view controller and either destroy it, or empty the array.
2. You're trying to write all the private messages into the same `JSQMessage` array. I notice in that view controller you have:

   ```
   var messageRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages")
   ```

   Is that the database connection you're working with? Each private message conversation should have a unique reference ID so that they do not overlap, otherwise every user will load up the same set of messages from Firebase.

Comment: if i destroy the messages, will the user be able to come back to that conversation?

Comment: I am using this tutorial(https://www.raywenderlich.com/140836/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat-2)  to implement the chat. I believe this function does the same thing you described. `deinit {
        if let refHandle = newMessageRefHandle {
            messageRef.removeObserver(withHandle: refHandle)
        }
        
        if let refHandle = updatedMessageRefHandle {
            messageRef.removeObserver(withHandle: refHandle)
        }
    }` but it is not really working

Comment: I also just made a third user and when I click on a user to send message the previous dialog with the two users still remain, like a group chat. Which is definitely not what I want

Comment: Looks like that's removing the observers but you're not destroying the controller. You either need to clear the data in the controller when switching users, or destroy the controller itself.

Comment: I am an extreme novice at swift and I have been trying for the past 4 hours to implement your answer. It is probably really simple but I am having the hardest time. What would be easier implementing this or using security to prevent other people from joining the thread once it's created between the two people. P.s I have also included my entire (excessively long view controller ) in the question

Comment: Added some more thoughts.

Comment: you were right it had to do with the way I was storing the messages. Thank you!!